# I want to open Datepicker pop-up through click on text only with HTML CSS

Tags: css, html, datepicker

I am using HTML5 Datepicker. And I want to open this datepicker after click on icon or text.

**CODE:**

```
<label for="YOURID">Through<label>
<input id="YOURID" type="date" />
```

I tried using with label but is not working. I want to use only HTML, CSS and javascript(NOT JQUERY).

But It should be work with label. So My first priority is, I want to implement(Make clickable text and open datepicker) with html css. Datepicker open should be after click on text.

Comment: can you provide working code..?

Comment: you can't achieve that with only HTML and CSS, you need to use js, it can be done with vanilla JS as well

Comment: The datepicker is browser specific. I don't think that this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Just add their JS If you don't want the input box to display then make its width to 10px in a way that only calendar icon appears

[pikaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday)

In your HTML

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

In your JS

```
var picker = new Pikaday({ field: document.getElementById('datepicker') });
```

Comment: This script does not use html5 datepicker.

Comment: Yes, If you want to use HTML5, I tried Sid answer in JSfiddle and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Not getting exactly what you want but i think this is what you are looking for

Try this!

```
  HTML    
  <label for="YOURID">Date Of Birth</label>
  <input type="date" name="dateofbirth" id="YOURID">

  CSS
  [type="date"] {
  background:#fff 
  url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/calendar_2.png)  97% 50% no-repeat ;
  }
  [type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: none;
  }
 [type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
 opacity: 0;
  }


body {
padding: 4em;
background: #e5e5e5;
font: 13px/1.4 Geneva, 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans 
Unicode', Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
label {
display: block;
      }
input {
border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #fff;
padding: 3px 5px;
box-shadow: inset 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
width: 190px;
      }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Sid. I want to open pop-up of datepicker after click on text.

Comment: sorry for late reply...this is working for me in chrome as well. Please check whether you have latest chrome installed.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML and Javascript date picker example below works in almost all browsers. It uses the native html *datetime-local* input type and falls back to Pikaday (with time) as a polyfill when datetime-local is not supported by the browser. To run it you need to download Pikaday from https://github.com/owenmead/Pikaday , extract pikaday.js and pikaday.css
and drop them in the same folder as the file containing this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pikaday.css"/>
    <script src="pikaday.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

function setDate(elementId, date) {
  // "elementId" is the element id of the date field to be updated and will be initialized to "date"
  // in the timezone the user is browsing from.

  if (elementId.type == "datetime-local") {
    // datetime-local is supported, set the initial date in ISO format and show it
    elementId.value = date.getFullYear() + '-'+
    ('0'+(date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
    ('0'+date.getDate()).slice(-2) + 'T' +
    ('0'+date.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' +
    ('0'+date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
  }
  else {
    // Note that even though we assign the datetime-local input type to time fields it will be read back as text unless
    // datetime-local is actually supported. 
    new Pikaday({
      field          : elementId,
      defaultDate    : date,
      setDefaultDate : true,
      showTime       : true,
      minutesStep    : 5,
      splitTimeView  : false,
      hours24format  : true,
      position       : 'bottom left'
    });
  }
}


function getDateAsString(elementId) {
  var dateAsString;

  if (elementId.type == "datetime-local") {
    dateAsString = elementId.value;
  }
  else {
    var val = elementId.value;
    // Convert time to ISO format which is the same format as that returned by datetime-local

    var month = val.substring(4,7);
    if (month == "Jan") month = "01";
    else if (month == "Feb") month = "02";
    else if (month == "Mar") month = "03";
    else if (month == "Apr") month = "04";
    else if (month == "May") month = "05";
    else if (month == "Jun") month = "06";
    else if (month == "Jul") month = "07";
    else if (month == "Aug") month = "08";
    else if (month == "Sep") month = "09";
    else if (month == "Oct") month = "10";
    else if (month == "Nov") month = "11";
    else if (month == "Dec") month = "12";

    var hour = val.substring(16,18);
    if (val.indexOf("PM") != -1) {
      hour = parseInt(hour);
      if (hour < 12) {
        // Have seen the likes of 21:15 PM returned by pikaday on firefox, hence the hour check
        hour = hour+12;            
      }
    }
    dateAsString = val.substring(11,15) + "-" + month + "-" + val.substring(8,10) + "T" + hour + ":" + val.substring(19,21);    
  }

  return dateAsString;
}


function getDate(elementId) {
   var ds = getDateAsString(elementId);
   var date = new Date(ds.substring(0,4), ds.substring(5,7)-1, ds.substring(8,10), ds.substring(11,13), ds.substring(14,16), ds.substring(17,19));
   return date;
}
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="setDate(document.getElementById('demo'), new Date());">
    <input type="datetime-local" id="demo"/>
    <br/><br/>
    <button type="button" onclick="alert(getDateAsString(document.getElementById('demo')))">Show date as string</button>
    <br/><br/>
    <button type="button" onclick="alert(getDate(document.getElementById('demo')))">Show date as date object</button>
  </body>

</html>
```